# JPA Hibernate : batch insert is not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly, h2, bulkinsert

I use H2 database in server mode with Wildfly 20.0.1.Final

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Import_Ordre")
public class ImportOrdre implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  private String osmozeId;

//getter/setter
}
```

persistence.xml

```
 <persistence-unit name="osmoze2" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>java:/H2DS_OSMOZE</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
     <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="25" />
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
```

The loop :

```
@Stateless
@Local(ImportOrdreDAO.class)
public class ImportOrdreDAOImpl implements ImportOrdreDAO {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName="osmoze2")
  private EntityManager em;

  public void create(Iterator<String> iter) {
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        ImportOrdre e = new ImportOrdre();
        String s = iter.next();
        e.setOsmozeId(s);
        em.persist(e);
    }
  }
}
```

And I don't get bulk insert (sample from a loop with hundreds of elements) :

```
21:40:23,436 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: insert into Import_Ordre (osmozeId) values (?)
21:40:23,436 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: insert into Import_Ordre (osmozeId) values (?)
21:40:23,436 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: insert into Import_Ordre (osmozeId) values (?)
```

H2 log :

```
*SQL l:46 #:1*/insert into Import_Ordre (osmozeId) values (?) {1: 'osmoze-6424'};
2021-01-18 21:40:23 jdbc[4]:
/*SQL l:46 #:1*/insert into Import_Ordre (osmozeId) values (?) {1: 'osmoze-6425'};
2021-01-18 21:40:23 jdbc[4]:
/*SQL l:46 #:1*/insert into Import_Ordre (osmozeId) values (?) {1: 'osmoze-6426'};
2021-01-18 21:40:23 jdbc[4]:
/*SQL t:33*/COMMIT;
```

I do want insert like :

```
insert into import_ordre (osmozeid) values ('a'),('b'),('c')
```

Comment: How this ends up in the database depends on how the JDBC driver handles batch inserts so this might be an issue with the H2 JDBC driver. You can debug into `org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister#insert(java.io.Serializable, java.lang.Object[], boolean[], int, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor)` and see how Hibernate uses the JDBC Batch API.

Answer (score -1):

Thing about adding some `Batch` annotation ont you entity.

```
@BatchSize(size=...)
@Entity
@Table(name="Import_Ordre")
public class ImportOrdre implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  private String osmozeId;

//getter/setter
}
```

Comment: Have you ever read the documentation of the annotation? The annotation is about configuring the size of batches for lazy loading, not batch insertion.